# netstat output: wider columns on OS X?

Tags: macos, network, catalina

I'm using netstat on OS X.  How do I get wider columns?

It looks like some of information (in Local Address column) is clipped for hostnames, IP and mac address.  I did not see anything in the manual.  Thanks

```
$ netstat
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp6       0      0  xxxx-macboo.1024  fe80::b3ac:b3c2:.1024  SYN_SENT   
tcp6       0      0  2601:18c:c900:50.64154 2a04:4e42:1c::76.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.11.64124        47.224.186.35.bc.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.11.64120        10.0.0.6.59092         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  10.0.0.11.64106        205.245.190.35.b.https ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe there are options to give you exactly what you want and prevent *Local Address* from being truncated (note that the entry beginning `2601:18c` in your example is an IPv6 address, not a MAC address). Option `-W` (*In certain displays, avoid truncating addresses*) seems that it will give what you want but it still truncates hostnames and IPv6 addresses.

The following `netstat` options can get you most of the way there:

`-l`    Print full IPv6 address

`-n`    Show network addresses as numbers...

Using a combination of those two options (`netstat -ln`)  will give you un-truncated IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Once you have those, you can use, eg `host`, to do a DNS lookup of the IP address in order to get the hostname if a `PTR` record exists for it.

Comment: Thanks.  Are people using netstat output in a different way?  I mean if it's truncated, how useful is it?

Comment: As FQDNs can be infinitely long (unlike IP addresses), the developers probably had to make a decision about how much data to show. It's still useful as IP addresses are displayed without truncation.

Comment: Is there another interface to obtain this data?  I.e. is there a mode where CSV is output?

Answer (score 0):

To get full hostnames for IPv4 addresses, I pipe `netstat -anp tcp` through Python, falling back on the IP if none available-

tidy_netstat.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import socket
import sys

ip_cache = dict()
NS_ADDYS = re.compile(r"^(\w+).*\D(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\s+(\S.+)$")


def get_ipv4_host(ip):
    if ip in ip_cache:
        return ip_cache[ip]
    try:
        info = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    except socket.herror:
        return
    if info and info[0]:
        ip_cache[ip] = info[0]
        return info[0]


while line := sys.stdin.readline():
    res = NS_ADDYS.match(line)
    if res:
        proto, srcip, dstip, state = res.groups()
        if proto != 'tcp4':
            continue
        srchost, dsthost = get_ipv4_host(srcip), get_ipv4_host(dstip)
        print("\t".join((srchost or srcip, dsthost or dstip, state)))
```

There's probably better ways, but this works for me.

Combined with a periodic runner, such as [watch](https://ports.macports.org/port/watch/), it becomes a useful way for seeing just what your machine and its apps are getting up to.

`% watch -d sh -c "'netstat -anp tcp | ./tidy_netstat.py'"`

I have a cronjob that periodically writes the dsthost to a sqlite table with a counter, just to see where my machine has been over time.

What's really interesting is, I'll run it just after boot, or after quitting all GUI proggies, and there will be one or two connections to unnamed hosts!

e.g. 17.57.144.23 - nearly always they belong to [an Apple netblock, like this one in 17.0.0.0/9](https://ip-netblocks.whoisxmlapi.com/lookup-report/yVR7NKNkg0).

Since then, I've been keeping an eye on those connections-

`% sudo tcpdump -vvvv -s 99999 -w /tmp/apple.pcap -i en5 net 17.0.0.0/9`

But they've all been TLS, so far, no viewable data. (FWIW I don't have Find My Mac enabled).

Comment: Interesting observation and thanks for the utility!